# Angular append query parameter to the same route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have the following Route setup in my app.routing.module

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/smart-parking/dashboard", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "locations-create", component: AddLocationComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: "smart-parking", loadChildren: () => import('./smartparking/smartparking.module').then((m => m.SmartParkingModule)), canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
// more routes here
]
```

"smar-parking" routing module is the following:

```js
 [

  {
    path: "", component: SidenavComponent,
    children: [
      {path: "", redirectTo: "dashboard", pathMatch:"full"},
      { path: "dashboard", component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: "insights", component: InsightsComponent},
      { path: ":organization/gateways/:id", component: GatewayComponent },
      { path: "setup/devices", component: SetupDevicesComponent}
    ]
  },
  
];
```

When I navigate to `/smart-parking/dashboard` on of the components is running the following code:

```js
this.router.navigate(
  ['.'],
  {
    relativeTo: this.route.parent,
    queryParams: queryParams,
    skipLocationChange: true,
    queryParamsHandling:"merge"
  }
)
```

Generally I want to append a query parameter in the url withougt changing the url. The problem is that it redirects me to the following url `/dashboard?queryparm=value` instad of `/smart-parking/'dashboard?queryparam=value`. I am thinking it has something to do with using `dashboard` as a children of `smart-parking` but cannot explain nor solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try relativeTo: this.route ?

Comment: Yes the same. I had it firstly to `this.route` but i had this issue. But I switched it to `parent` to see if it will work

Comment: In your smart-parking routing module, put your redirect route (to dashboard) as the last one in the children array, instead of the first?

Comment: I also suppose you import the SmartParkingModule in your imports of the AppModule? Try deleting it from the imports in the AppModule as it's lazy loading. You shouldn't have any dependencies in the AppModule though.

Comment: @W.S. you were right! I removed, but now I cannot 'attach" the query parameters on the url. It is as if `route.navigate` doesn't work at all!

Comment: Where do the `queryParams`, which you're using in the component, come from? And at which point in the component are you trying the change the url query params?

Comment: I would put your redirect route, as last in the children's array and use `this.router.navigate(['/smart-parking/'dashboard'], { queryParams, queryParamsHandling: 'merge' } )`

Comment: queryParams are set up in `onNgInit`. They are derived from making a call to a method returning an obsevable using angular firestore library. To be honest I dont want to navigate to the same route but to the route already activated.

Comment: What's the difference for you between 'the same route' and 'the route already activated'? Any possibility to share a StackBiltz with a minimal setup of your environment?

Comment: The navigation is happening from within a a component common for all others. A mat toolbar. So it should be agnostic of the activated route.makes sense?

Comment: check: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bkkuee?file=src/app/smart-parking/sidenav/sidenav.component.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4gzxnq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts My code needs route navigation to happen from app.module, because it's common, for all feature modules. But as you can see from the stackblitz it won't work. The same happens in my code locally. Navigation from app.component.ts doesn't trigger

Comment: Upon loading your StackBlitz, the app properly navigates to `/smart-parking/dashboard?hello=world` as defined in your `app.component.ts`. What other behaviour do you expect?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4gzxnq?file=src/app/app.component.ts can you take another look? I replaces route to `['.']` and `activatedRoute.firstChild` with `this.activatedRoute`. The expected behaviour would be to be able to apend from whenever I was queryParameters  withoug having to navigate explicitely to the current route. Isn't this thie usage of relative urls?

Comment: You can work with `this.router.navigateByUrl` and get the current url from any component using `window.location.href`, put it in a `new URL(window.location.href)`, manipulate the searchParams where needed and pass the revised href to `navigateByUrl`.

Comment: That's what I thought, so `ActivatedRoute` gives you the route for the component where you inject it or run it, did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes, your statement seems correct.

Comment: I was with the imrpession that `ActivatedRoute` would give you the activated route in general. But I gues this `Provides access to information about a route associated with a component that is loaded in an outlet. Use to traverse the RouterState tree and extract information from nodes.` says it all

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue related to this that was caused when lazy loaded modules were being used

A fix was added, `relativeLinkResolution` - might be worth trying. The Angular team added it as a config option so it wouldn't be a breaking change

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    relativeLinkResolution: 'corrected'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

- https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#relativeLinkResolution

Comment: I will try ty but i think corrected is the default value since v11 and i am using v13

Comment: unfotunatelly it didn't work. I also do `console.log(this.route.snapshot.url` and I get an empty array

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me is to go with the following:

```js
this.router.navigate(
    ['.'],
    {
        relativeTo: this.route.firstChild,
        queryParams: queryParams,
        queryParamsHandling: "merge"
    }
)
```

I am not sure this is the correct solution. Any ideas would be nice.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.If I am in `smart-parking/insights` it navigates back to `smart-parking` which redirects me to `smart-parking/dashboard`. So still frustrated